# add(T) in List cannot be applied to Java.lang.Number

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am trying to make a generic List that can contain only Numbers. When i try to add an Integer to it, it gives the following error.

> add(T) in List cannot be applied to Java.lang.Number

```
public class QueryHelper<T extends Number> {

    private List<T> records;

    public void query(QueryTypes queryType) {
        records = new ArrayList();
        records.add((Number)new Integer(90));        
    }
}
```

What is causing this problem?

Comment: `Integer` and `T` may both be `Number`s, but that doesn't mean an `Integer` is a `T`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `List<T>` where `T extends Number` can be a `List<Number>`, a `List<Integer>`, a `List<Double>`, etc...

You can't add an `Integer` to a `List<Double>`. Hence the compilation error.

If you want to be able to add any `Number` instance to that list, simply define it as

```
private List<Number> records;
```

which means you won't need the generic type parameter `T`.